# Image in ListView does not follow the width given and has different widths in different rows

Tags: android, android-layout

I have made a custom list view with an imageview and textview in a row.
Some of the images are not aligning up with the other images and it looks terrible. Below is a screenshot of how it looks.
[image: Sceenshot of the app]

Notice how the icon in music and albums are taking extra space.

The xml for the row is below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:layout_width = "match_parent"
          android:layout_height = "match_parent"
          android:background = "#F7BA70"
          android:orientation = "horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id = "@+id/categoryListRowImage"
    android:layout_width = "30dp"
    android:layout_height = "50dp"
    android:layout_gravity = "center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight = "0.32"
    android:adjustViewBounds = "true"
    android:contentDescription = "Image Description"
    android:scaleType = "fitXY"
    android:src = "@drawable/music" />

<TextView
    android:id = "@+id/categoryListRowId"
    android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:visibility = "gone" />

<TextView
    android:id = "@+id/categoryListRowText"
    android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_height = "50dp"
    android:layout_gravity = "center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight = "3"
    android:gravity = "center_vertical"
    android:paddingEnd = "20dp"
    android:paddingLeft = "20dp"
    android:paddingRight = "20dp"
    android:paddingStart = "20dp"
    android:textColor = "#FFF"
    android:textSize = "24sp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width = "20dp"
    android:layout_height = "20dp"
    android:layout_gravity = "center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginRight = "20dp"
    android:scaleType = "fitXY"
    android:src = "@drawable/white_arrow" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have used the same icon for all the images

How can the same listview give me different width in images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you giving weight 0.32 to imageview and 3 to your textview. Remove the weight from your ImageView and give weight 1 to your textView that should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for this. But can i know why that actually happened. Wont the weight affect all of the items in the list and not only single items?

Comment: Since you have given weight to ImageView and TextView and your textview is wrap content so according to the textsize the width was getting effected.

Answer (score 0):

You should give a width of 0dp if you are specifying weight.

In your case, remove the weight from the image. 
In textview, make weight = 1 and width = 0dp

Comment: As @sumit pointed out in his answer, the weight was causing the issue. Thanks for informing me about the weight and width conflicts.